# puppeteer gives error 'Node is not visible' on click on SVG elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, puppeteer

Currently I am writing a script to gather some data from this site. http://www.easycredit-bbl.de/de/n/spielberichte/2016-17/nachbericht/2016-09-23-bam-fra/#specialnavi=34

The page loads with the right most rectangle highlighted. I need to click on the panels of the SVG figure in order to load data on the write of the screen to copy. Unfortunately when I try to click I receive this error

> "Error: Node is not visible"

Any advice or workarounds? Maybe clicking not on the element itself just a section of the screen?

Comment: there is an open issue at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1247

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure the element is loaded & visible before clicking on it?
Maybe something like this before you click on it?

```
await page.waitFor(<selector>,{visible:true})
```

Comment: `await this.page.waitForSelector('input#username', {visible: true});`

Answer (score 5):

A good practice to debug this is to use:

```
await page.evaluate(()=> {
    document.querySelector("#settings").click()
})
```

since that will tell you if it is a puppeteer issue or not, by using a browser native command inside the page itself

Comment: What do you mean by browser native command? puppeteer is a node.js library, it cannot be run in a browser, on a web page.

Comment: @saitam puppeteer controls a headless chrome browser via devtools protocol. I meant running js within the browser using puppeteer's API, as opposed to calling a puppeteer function (which does more things under the hook)